# How to output command prompt data with correcct endoing to text file?

Tags: windows, command-prompt

I wrote a .bat file as:

```
SET FILE=%username%.txt
wmic path win32_VideoController get name>>%FILE%
systeminfo >> %FILE%
```

But the file contains the following data:

```
Name                       
Intel(R) UHD Graphics 630  
਍潈瑳丠浡㩥††††††††吠䍘䭈均卋〰ഷ伊⁓慎敭›†††††............
```

How to solve the wrong encoding problem?

Thanks.